# Laravel index blade mostrar nombre de usuarios en el perfil

Tags: laravel

Quisiera saber como puedo mostrar el nombre de los usuarios en su perfil, es decir mostrar el nombre de una foreign key.

Este es mi controlador

```
public function index()
    {
        $profiles = Profile::all(); 
        return view('profile.index', compact('profiles')); 
    }
```

y este es mi index.blade en el cual solo me imprime los id de los users y yo quiero los nombres

```
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($profiles as $profile)

         <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{$profile->user_id}}</h5>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>    

        @endforeach
    </div>

@endsection
```

Las migraciones

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); //no acepta valores negativos 
            $table->text('descripcion', 45)->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('telefono', 45)->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('direccion', 45)->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('genero');
            $table->string('fecha_nac')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        });
    }

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenida, para que te podamos ayudar mejor necesitamos saber si estas trabajando las relaciones de Laravel en tus modelos, del mismo modo si es una relación uno a uno o uno a varios

Comment: Para poder ayudarte necesito saber el contenido del modelo Profile y la migracion correspondiente, porque si tiene este el atributo nombre entonces no hace falta acceder por una llave foranea. lo otro seria de ser necesaria la llave foranea se necesita la tabla donde esta esa columna y ver como construir la relacion para poder traer ese dato con la consulta.

Comment: ¿Cuántos perfiles puede tener un usuario?

Comment: Pueden tener un solo perfil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Dado que estas trabajando bajo una relación de **1 a 1** entonces no necesitas un ciclo `foreach` para iterar los datos obtenidos de la consulta.

Por otro lado no logras obtener el nombre del usuario al que le *pertenece* dicho perfil sino únicamente su llave foránea, pues estas haciendo un `SELECT` general pero a la tabla de `profiles` con el método `all()` entonces *esta consultada esta asilada de conocer con que valor esta vinculada dicha llave*

**Procedimiento**

Si el usuario solo tiene un perfil entonces bastaría con que hagas lo siguiente:

En el modelo `User` declara un método llamado que indicará: *Un usuario tiene solo un perfil*

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

Posterior en el modelo `Profile` con lo siguiente, que indica un perfil solo pertenece a un usuario:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Ahora para recuperar los datos del usuario con su perfil deberías hacer lo siguiente:

Accedemos a los datos del modelo `Profile` para traer los datos, pero dado que es una relación de uno a uno entonces debemos usar `find()` o `findOrFail()` que recibe como parámetro el `id` del perfil que quieres consultar.

Ahora encadenamos el método `user` que declaraste en el modelo `Profile` para obtener los datos del usuario vinculado con dicho perfil.

```
$data = Profile::find($id)->user;
```

Recuerda en invocar el *namespace* del modelo en la parte superior del controlador donde estás haciendo la consulta así:

```
use App\Profile;
```

Ahora para acceder al nombre del user dueño de ese perfil pudieramos tener lo siguiente:

```
{{ $data->user->name }}
```

Donde:

- `$data` es el nombre de la propiedad que contiene nuestra consulta
- `user` es el nombre del método contenido en el modelo `Profile`
- `name` es el nombre de la columna que estaría guardando el nombre del usuario *dueño* del perfil

**Referencias**

- [Relaciones en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)
- [Retorno de registros fila por fila](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)